# Validating XML Data with XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have a really large XML file that has some bad dates in it (i.e. 1-11-1012, 11-32-1525) which cause processing to fail. I just received a copy of the XSD schema for the XML file. Basically I want to be able to use the XSD to show me where the bad dates are in the XML file, is that a realistic expectation? If so, can someone point me in the right direction? Are there any tools I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Any XMl editor that supports XSD can do this for you. Download a evaluation copy of Oxygen XML editor.

Comment: Would something like Visual Studio Express work?

Answer (score 0):

The standard xs:date type defined in XSD requires the ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD, whereas your dates appear to be in M-D-YYYY format. It's not easy using standard XSD mechanisms to validate such dates. One option is to apply a transformation to your data prior to validation; the transformation should convert the dates from M-D-YYYY form to YYYYY-MM-DD. Another approach might be the saxon:preprocess extension in Saxon's implementation of XSD 1.1 - this effectively allows you to extend or restrict the lexical space of a data type without changing its value space. See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/index.html#!schema-processing/extensions11/preprocess

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong in guessing that your dates were in M-D-YYYY format. If that were the case, 1-11-1012 would not be invalid. So sorry, I may have misread your question.